# How to restore data from SharedPreferences to TextView when app starts?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My app save text from TextView in SharedPreferences (type String). Then in other five TextView showing the last 5 numbers from SharedPreferences. It's work very good.

There was a problem.How to restore data from SharedPreferences to all five TextView when app starts?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button btnSave;
private Button btnCallCalc;
private TextView txtNowDigit;
private TextView firstDigit;
private TextView secondDigit;
private TextView thirdDigit;
private TextView fourthDigit;
private TextView fifthDigit;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CALL_CALC = 100;
public static final int RESULT_OK = 111;
public static final String DIGIT_EXTRA = "DIGIT_EXTRA";
public static final String KEY_FIRST_DIGIT = "KEY_FIRST_DIGIT";
public static final String KEY_SECOND_DIGIT = "KEY_SECOND_DIGIT";
public static final String KEY_THIRD_DIGIT = "KEY_THIRD_DIGIT";
public static final String KEY_FOURTH_DIGIT = "KEY_FOURTH_DIGIT";
public static final String KEY_FIFTH_DIGIT = "KEY_FIFTH_DIGIT";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    btnCallCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call_calc);
    txtNowDigit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.now_result);
    firstDigit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_digit);
    secondDigit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.second_digit);
    thirdDigit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.third_digit);
    fourthDigit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fourth_digit);
    fifthDigit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fifth_digit);

    btnCallCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalculatorActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CALL_CALC);
        }
    });


    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString(KEY_FIFTH_DIGIT, sp.getString(KEY_FOURTH_DIGIT, null));
            editor.putString(KEY_FOURTH_DIGIT, sp.getString(KEY_THIRD_DIGIT, null));
            editor.putString(KEY_THIRD_DIGIT, sp.getString(KEY_SECOND_DIGIT, null));
            editor.putString(KEY_SECOND_DIGIT, sp.getString(KEY_FIRST_DIGIT, null));
            editor.putString(KEY_FIRST_DIGIT, txtNowDigit.getText().toString());
            editor.apply();

            setSavedDigits();
        }
    });
}

private void setSavedDigits() {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);

    fifthDigit.setText(sp.getString(KEY_FIRST_DIGIT, null));
    fourthDigit.setText(sp.getString(KEY_SECOND_DIGIT, null));
    thirdDigit.setText(sp.getString(KEY_THIRD_DIGIT, null));
    secondDigit.setText(sp.getString(KEY_FOURTH_DIGIT, null));
    firstDigit.setText(sp.getString(KEY_FIFTH_DIGIT, null));
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        return;
    }

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_CALL_CALC:
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }
            String digit = data.getStringExtra(DIGIT_EXTRA);
            txtNowDigit.setText(String.valueOf(digit));
            break;

        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might encourage help if you post the minimum code necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setSavedDigits()` after

```
fifthDigit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fifth_digit);
```

in `onCreate` method.

Comment: @ЕгорУрбанович: Happy to help  :)